# How to set the direction of the arrowhead?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

This refers to my previous question: [How to draw line automatically by reading coordinates from file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55251989/how-to-draw-line-automatically-by-reading-coodinates-from-file-in-d3#55251989)

I need to add an arrow head at one side, based on one column `flag` (`R` for right, `L` for left):

```
x1,y1,x2,y2,Flag
1,2,3,2,L
3,3,5,3,R 
5,3,6,3,L 
7,5,7,5,R
8,6,8,6,L 
9,7,2,7,L
```

How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious solution here would be setting the marker as `marker-end` or `marker-start` according to the value of the `flag` property.

However, on a second thought, we can do something more interesting here: we can set all markers as `marker-end` and, according to the `flag`, we **swap** the `x1` and `x2` properties, making:

- `x1` smaller than `x2` if flag is `R`;
- `x1` bigger than `x2` if flag is `L`;

It can be done with:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
  if ((d.flag === "L" && d.x1 < d.x2) || (d.flag === "R" && d.x1 > d.x2)) {
    d.x1 = d.x2 + (d.x2 = d.x1, 0);
  }
});
```

Here is the demo:

```js
const csv = `x1,y1,x2,y2,flag
1,2,3,2,L
3,3,5,4,R
5,3,6,3,L
7,5,8,5,R
8,6,9,6,L
9,7,2,8,L`;

const data = d3.csvParse(csv, function(d) {
  d.x1 = +d.x1 * 20;
  d.y1 = +d.y1 * 15;
  d.x2 = +d.x2 * 20;
  d.y2 = +d.y2 * 15;
  return d;
});

data.forEach(function(d) {
  if ((d.flag === "L" && d.x1 < d.x2) || (d.flag === "R" && d.x1 > d.x2)) d.x1 = d.x2 + (d.x2 = d.x1, 0);
});

const svg = d3.select("svg");

const marker = svg.append("defs")
  .append("marker")
  .attr("id", "marker")
  .attr("viewBox", "0 0 10 10")
  .attr("refX", "5")
  .attr("refY", "5")
  .attr("markerWidth", "6")
  .attr("markerHeight", "6")
  .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", "M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z");

const enterSelection = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("x1", d => d.x1)
  .attr("y1", d => d.y1)
  .attr("x2", d => d.x2)
  .attr("y2", d => d.y2)
  .attr("marker-end", "url(#marker)")
  .style("stroke-width", "1px")
  .style("stroke", "black");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Since your values are too small I'm multiplying them here, so we can better see the lines. Also, because you didn't share any marker, I'm using the one at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/marker).

Comment: Thanks Can I keep text on the line? if I pass some text for each line, it should be displayed on the line.

Comment: @Manish I have no idea of what you're talking about... anyway, it's never a good practice at SO asking questions on the comments (comments are only for clarifications/discussions about the current answer). Therefore, if you have a different issue please ask a new question with all the relevant details and, the most important, **with your current attempt**, even if it's not working.